# How to assign the result of a _.each loop to a variable?

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

The following code creates a `Document`. Once that's finished it searches for all the documents and push them into a list called `this.documents`:

```
store.create(document).then(() => {
  store.find().then((results) => {
    this.documents = []
    _.each(results, (result) => {
      this.documents.push(result.toJSON())
    })
  })
})
```

It works fine. But I thought that, instead of pushing the items into a list, I could directly assign the `_.each` loop into a variable:

```
store.create(document).then(() => {
  store.find().then((results) => {
    this.documents = _.each(results, (result) => {
      return result.toJSON()
    })
    console.log(this.documents)
  })
})
```

`console.log(this.documents)`, though doesn't output the individual items but this:

> [ParseObjectSubclass, ParseObjectSubclass, ParseObjectSubclass,
>   ParseObjectSubclass, ParseObjectSubclass, ParseObjectSubclass,
>   ParseObjectSubclass, ParseObjectSubclass, ParseObjectSubclass,
>   ParseObjectSubclass]

What's the correct way of doing what I want to accomplish?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you want `_.map` instead of `_.each`.

Comment: Hey, it worked. But with `return` I thought `_.map` already returned stuff by default. Why is it necessary to add `return`?

Comment: @alexchenco i'm guessing its because of the es6 lambda/arrow function.

Comment: @alexchenco: the body of your arrow function is a block, you need to return explicitly. If it is only an expression, you don't need `return`.